# Psychopy unexpected keyword argument 'languageStyle'

Tags: python, python-3.x, psychopy

I saw that psychopy now has support for RTL language: 
http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/textstim.html
https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/reshaping-english-text-to-arabic/4235/16

I used this manual to install the latest version using conda:
http://psychopy.org/installation.html

My version is: 1.90.2 with Python 3.5

However, when init TextStim with languageStyle I get an error:

```
from psychopy import visual 
text_stim = visual.TextStim(self.window, height = height, wrapWidth = wrapWidth, bold= True, text= sentence, pos = (0,0) , color='white', languageStyle='RTL')
```

Any idea how can I use it?

Comment: That is the documentation for psychopy 3.0. The parameter was probably introduced somewhere between your 1.9 and 3.0.

Comment: Please note that PsychoPy is only tested by the developers on Python 2.7 and 3.6. If you want to use Python 3, please consider switching to 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, @deceze is correct, this feature in the latest beta, available for download from this page: https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/releases rather than the latest stable release available from http://psychopy.org/installation.html

***EDIT:*** *actually I see that you're installing PsychoPy via `pip` under Anaconda. I guess the `pip` version is also lagging behind the current beta release. You might need to clone or download from the PsychoPy GitHUb repository if you want the latest developer release running under your own Python installation.*

Note that this feature still doesn't handle multi-line text correctly in Python experiments (the text flows from right to left but also from bottom-to-top). This is due to a limitation in the underlying `pyglet` library we use for drawing text. However, the latest betas also allow for generating online Javascript experiments that can be run from a browser. These handle Arabic text correctly without any issues whatsoever (and with no need to specify the language style setting at all).

Comment: Thanks, all I need it to present a one-line TextStim RTL, it should work right? To any RTL language? (e.g. Arabic, Hebrew, etc). So should I just download the text.py from GitHub and replace my file with it?

Comment: Yes, although I only tested it with Arabic, but I hope that other languages will work just by selecting the `RTL` style.

Comment: Please check my follow-up question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947920/psychopy-chars-spaces-arent-equal-in-rtl-language-style