# Psychopy chars spaces aren't equal in RTL language style

Tags: python-3.x, psychopy

I am using RTL language style in Psychopy 1.9 to display sentences in Hebrew. However, there are some randomly added spaces between characters.
Please see the following presented output (Following by the way this word/phrase should look like):

[image: בגלל שנועם]

[image: שהכדורגלן]

Image 1 - בגלל שנועם

Image 2 - שהכדורגלן

Please notice the fault added spaces

Thanks!

Comment: Some issues with display in other languages have been resolved simply by using another font. What font is this, and have you tried others? Also to narrow this down, what does the spacing look like if the RTL setting is not applied?

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill I tried several other fonts but it didn't help.. I wrote the way the spacing should look like under the images - no spaces at all in the second image, and a single space in the upper image

Comment: I get that you've provided a text version above, but we need to know if the issue is with displaying the characters in PsychoPy in the first place, or due to the manipulation of making them appear right-to-left. So can you confirm that if you display a text stimulus with this string of characters, but do _not_ select `RTL` as the language style, whether the characters have incorrect spacing (ignore that they will be displayed in the wrong direction).

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill Actually you are right - when I do not select RTL but LTR the spaces still appears. All I do is read the words from .csv and present them - any idea what may cause it?

Comment: No, but this does again make me think that this is an issue with particular fonts. You could try using a monospace font and see what happens there. I'd also suggest taking this question (working in these comments) to the forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org because this doesn't really look like something that will be resolved here at Stack Overflow as there isn't going to a coding-based suggestion for you.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill Thank you, will do. Can you please just elaborate what do you mean by monospace font ?

Comment: Google will be your friend here. You will have several installed by default by your operating system but I don’t know which would be best for showing Hebrew characters. Something in the Courier family would be a good start but really it depends on what you have available on your particular system.